OpenShift cluster update failing due to an unavailable monitoring operator
I attempted to update RedHat OpenShift Cluster from version 4.13.46 to 4.14.34. The update so far has been completed on 29 of 33 ClusterOperators and 0 of 6 nodes before it stopped progressing as the "Cluster operator monitoring is not available". Before the update, everything worked completely fine including previous updates such as 4.12.61 > 4.13.46.
I was able to perform the following diagnostics:
$ oc get co monitoring

NAME         VERSION   AVAILABLE   PROGRESSING   DEGRADED   SINCE   MESSAGE
monitoring   4.13.46   False       True          True       25h     waiting for Alertmanager object changes failed: waiting for Alertmanager openshift-monitoring/main: context deadline exceeded



$ oc logs alertmanager-main-0


ts=2024-08-25T13:40:42.182Z caller=dispatch.go:354 level=error component=dispatcher msg="Notify for alerts failed" num_alerts=1 err="Critical/email[0]: notify retry canceled after 10 attempts: send STARTTLS command: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"
ts=2024-08-25T13:40:57.202Z caller=notify.go:732 level=warn component=dispatcher receiver=Critical integration=email[0] msg="Notify attempt failed, will retry later" attempts=1 err="send STARTTLS command: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"

$ oc get logs alertmanager-main-1

ts=2024-08-25T13:40:57.182Z caller=dispatch.go:354 level=error component=dispatcher msg="Notify for alerts failed" num_alerts=1 err="Critical/email\[0\]: notify retry canceled after 10 attempts: send STARTTLS command: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"
ts=2024-08-25T13:40:57.197Z caller=notify.go:732 level=warn component=dispatcher receiver=Critical integration=email\[0\] msg="Notify attempt failed, will retry later" attempts=1 err="send STARTTLS command: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"

How can I solve this and push the update further?
I have already tried the following solution which is similar to my issue, but not the same (all pods within co monitoring are in status "Running"). Unfortunately, no success.
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/7026005
